# Gridview paging error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I'm trying to enable paging for my `gridview`, however I'm always getting error:

> "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"
>   If i ignore the error the gridview creates the paging and works fine, but there is an error ignored...
>   This is my grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDeslocFinal" runat="server" Height="181px" Width="1042px" OnRowDataBound="gvDeslocFinal_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvDeslocFinal_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDeslocFinal_PageIndexChanging" OnSorted="gvDeslocFinal_Sorted" AllowPaging="True" OnRowCreated="gvDeslocFinal_RowCreated" PageIndex="1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Utilizador" HeaderText="Utilizador" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Carro" HeaderText="Carro" />...
            <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden-field" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Detalhes">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" Text="ver detalhes" OnClick="lnkEdit_Click" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="False" Height="30px" />

    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Height="20px" />
</asp:GridView>


protected void gvDeslocFinal_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gvDeslocFinal.EditIndex >= 0)
        return;
    BindGrid();
}
```

BindGrid function:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    try
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < GlobalOffline.DesTerm.Length; i++)
        {


            string sDataIn = smtgh;
...


            string sCodigo = GlobalOffline.DesTerm[i].Codigo;

            string[] sRow = new string[] { sCarro, ..., sCodigo };
            GlobalOffline.dtResult.Rows.Add(sRow);
        }

        gvDeslocFinal.DataSource = GlobalOffline.dtResult;
        gvDeslocFinal.VirtualItemCount = GlobalOffline.dtResult.Rows.Count;
        GlobalOffline.bDetails = false;
        gvDeslocFinal.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: have you set breakpoints and verified where the error is at?

Comment: yes, i've put some breakpoints and the error occur on the BindGrid()

Comment: Where is your code for BindGrid()? That is where the issue is going to be.

Comment: is when gridview.databind() is called

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see exactly where this is failing? Can you post the code for BindGrid()?